# implementing generic interfaces in c#

Tags: c#, generics

how can we inherit generic interfaces in to a generic class? 
I have tried below code and getting error message: "Bc' does not implement interface member 'ConsoleApplication3.iB.showval(int, int)". How it could be solved?

```
interface iB<X, Y> 
{
    void storeval(X p1,Y p2);
    void getval();
}
class Bc<X,Y>:iB<int,int>
{
    private X _dm1;
    private Y _dm2;
    public void storeval(X p1,Y p2) 
    {
        this._dm1 = p1;
        this._dm2 = p2;
    }
    public void getval() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}",this._dm1,this._dm2);
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Bc<string, bool> b1 = new Bc<string, bool>();
        b1.storeval("AppScienti",true);
        b1.getval();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not inheriting a generic interface - it inherits a fully defined instance of a generic interface.

Since you inherit `iB<int,int>`, you need to implement

```
public void storeval(int p1, int p2) {
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you could inherit `iB<X,Y>`, in which case your implementation of the interface would have worked:

```
class Bc<X,Y> : iB<X,Y> {
    ...
}
```

In either case, the parameters of the interface methods dependent on type parameters of the generic interface need to match the type parameters that you specify when inheriting the interface.

Answer (score 0):

With `class Bc<X, Y> : iB<int, int>` you define a new generic class, with two new generic type parameters, that happens to implement `iB<int, int>`. It's more clear if you rename them: `class Bc<NewX, NewY> : iB<int, int>`.

Your two new generic type parameters have nothing to do with the parameters defined by the interface. You can now declare a `new Bc<string, bool>` variable while the class still implements `iB<int, int>`.

You'll have to alter your method signature to let it implement `iB<int, int>.storeval(int, int)`:

```
public void storeval(int p1, int p2)
```

If you change your `Bc` class to inherit the generic parameters like this:

```
class Bc<X, Y> : iB<X, Y>
```

You can instantiate one like this:

```
var bcInt = new Bc<int, int>();
```